# Wordpress function, Run using Crontab

Tags: functions, wp-cron, cron

I have disabled cronjobs on my nginx server, as it is better to run from crontab.

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);
```

How could I run a custom wordpress function using Crontab, once per day?

This thread seems to offer a solution but it is not explained well enough in my opinion and might pose a security risk:
[execute function in wordpress plugin using crontab](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/259634/execute-function-in-wordpress-plugin-using-crontab)

On another note even if I disable WP_Cron, would `wp_schedule_single_event()` still work? As it would be easier to implement a solution this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);
```

This line disables the **default** behaviour of WP Cron. Which is being triggered by a user that visits the site. This is bad for a couple of reasons (nobody might visit, tasks are started via apache handler instead of PHP CLI, ...).

Now, if you have disabled it, you **need** another way to run WP Cron. Using crontab you could add an entry like so

```
*/5 * * * * php /absolute/path/to/wordpress_instance/wp-cron.php
```

Now wp-cron.php will run every 5 minutes via PHP CLI. This way your scheduled tasks will still run.

**If you disable the default cron and don't have an alternative as mentioned above, various WordPress functions may fail to execute!**

---

If you want to run a specific task once per day, you can [`wp_schedule_event()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_event/) with the recurrence being `daily`.

Comment: Also do you recommend hooking the wp_schedule_event to 'init' i.e. 'add_action( 'init', 'register_daily_event');'  ?

Comment: @JoannaMikalai No. If you call `wp_schedule_event` multiple times, it will schedule multiple events. You can avoid this by checking via `wp_next_scheduled` ([as shown here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_event/#comment-2277)). I usually put this in the plugin activation hook

Comment: ok but I just have a simple function that I would like to schedule. Not sure if I should create an entire plugin for that, or if there is an easier way. Perhaps some example code would be helpful.

Comment: The code reference has a couple of examples. You need to put this code somewhere, a plugin seems the right choice unless your change is theme specific. You can call it in the `init` hook, I just personally would not. You could alternatively create a function that registers this via the click of a button or similar